# matplotlit + PyQt5: replace a canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

To this question I am referring to:

Link1: https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt5.html

To be exactly, I am referring to this part from above link:

```
class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):
    """Simple canvas with a sine plot."""

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2*pi*t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
```

I want to change the canvas above to this one:

Link2: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/fig_x.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-fig-x-py

I am a newbie to `matplotlib`. Although I tried a lot but it still doesnot work. Thus I would like to ask if someone could do the replacement, which I could understand how matplotlib works.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. Maybe it would be better to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (keyword is *minimal* here), instead of trying to modify the code from the example, which is probably overly complex.

In any case to replace the sin wave used by the original [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt5.html) with the cross for the [second example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/fig_x.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-fig-x-py), you need to store the reference to the `Figure` object in the base canvas `__init__` function

```
import matplotlib.lines as lines

class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)  # <------
        # replace all references to fig by self.fig in the rest of the code
```

Then replace the code for the `MyStaticMplCanvas` class with the code from the example:

```
class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):
    """Simple canvas with a sine plot."""

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        l1 = lines.Line2D([0, 1], [0, 1], transform=self.fig.transFigure, figure=self.fig)
        l2 = lines.Line2D([0, 1], [1, 0], transform=self.fig.transFigure, figure=self.fig)
        self.fig.lines.extend([l1, l2])
```